# Assigning a function call to a variable

Tags: c++

To my understanding,

```
bool conditional = getTrueOrFalse();
```

will set conditional to what `getTrueOrFalse()` was at that exact line in the code.

How can I make it to where every time the variable `conditional` is used, it will call `getTrueOrFalse()` (as `getTrueOrFalse()` switches between true and false at different points throughout the program)? Am I able to set `conditional` to a different boolean-returning function later on?

Comment: This isn't at all clear.  Can you add some (pseudo)code to illustrate what you mean?

Comment: If you want to call to `getTrueOrFalse()`, then in your program write `getTrueOrFalse()` instead of `conditional`. Or are we missing some other important detail?

Comment: Short of a non-standard property-like interface (Visual C++ has such a thing) a preprocessor workup (egads that is hideous to think about) is possibly your only option. But why not just use `getTrueOrFalse()` ?

Comment: @SJuan76 But what if I needed to replace all instances of `getTrueOrFalse()` with `isSunShining()` later on? Wouldn't assigning a function call to a variable be the best way to do that?

Comment: If you're worried about what result you want to return, why not make a wrapper function? You could have `determineTrueOrFalse()` just be a one line function that returns the result of `getTrueOrFalse`, or if later you change your mind, you change it to `isSunShining`. Or you just skip the extra step and use find and replace in your tool of choice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try [function pointers](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function).

```
#include <functional>

std::function<bool()> conditional = &getTrueOrFalse;  // no evaluation yet

if ( conditional() )     // actual evaluation
{

} else {

}
conditional = &isSunShining;  // no evaluation yet: just point to something else
```

The OP isn't clear because you are not thinking about functional evaluation.  You must ask yourself, *when do I actually want to evaluate the function?*  When you use the parentheses, you are **actually evaluating** the function or the function pointer.  In your OP example, you have, technically already evaluated the function once and assigned it to the boolean `conditional`.

If you want an evaluation at a later point in your program, you will have to call the function again, explicitly, or implicitly, through a function pointer like my snippet above.

Also note that the boolean `conditional` is just a simple memory location with a binary representation of true/false - it has no idea of a *refresh my value on read*.  However, if you use the std::function<> `conditional` instead (like in my snippet), you can re-evaluate it every time you use the parenthesis operator.

Just for reference, there are many other ways to accomplish essentially the same feat:

- raw C-style function pointers (lhs)
- C++11 lambda (rhs)
- functors : classes with operator() (rhs)

lhs = left-hand side or where you store the address

rhs = implementation of your operation

Comment: How is it different from just calling `getTrueOrFalse()` directly? After all, you still have to put `()`.

Comment: @VladLazarenko it is an extra level of indirection (you can delay the call for later or assign it to be something else).  In an abstract way, it's like the extra level of indirection provided for by a variable `int x;` as opposed to a constant/fixed number `42`.  For example, that `std::function<>` can actually be an argument to a function (like a callback).  The caller can decide what to pass in.